# How to apply special formatting to R Markdown inline code?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

**DISCLAIMER** - this is obviously an oversimplified example, however I consider it the clearest to get the point accross.

Suppose we have the following (using the included iris dataset):

```
r1 <- cor.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
r2 <- cor.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)
```

Now suppose we want to build a following function:

```
gen_report <- function(x){
 if (x$p.value < .05) {
   paste("The correlation is statistically significant.")
 } else {
   paste("The correlation is not statistically significant.")
 }
}
```

Now suppose we want to use the function **inline** inside of an R markdown document. Just to clarify, when I say *inline*, I am thinking outside of a R markdown code chunk. The output of the `gen_report` function should happen inline with the text in the R Markdown document, with no visible code or the "output box" that usually appears.

It is fairly easy to do so. The following:

```
We have examined the correlation between Sepal Length and Sepal Width. `r gen_report(r1)` 

We have also examined the correlation between Sepal Length and Petal Length. `r gen_report(r2)`
```

will result in the correct output inline in the text. However, I am struggling to find a way to make the words "is" or "is not" *italic* in the output. Any ideas on how to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't it work with asterisk around the words? Like this: `paste("The correlation *is* statistically significant.")`

Comment: It does! Thank you for the quick reply! This confuses me very much because as far as I knew, asterisks are used in Markdown itslef and not in R code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Markdown code within the pasted R text like this:

```
paste("The correlation *is* statistically significant.")
```

Asterisks around words make them appear in italics.

See [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_intro.html) for more examples how you can style your output with Markdown formatting.