# How to apply code formatting to R Markdown inline code?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

suppose I want to print a list of variables in my markdown file and I want to highlight them from the rest of the text using code style. For example using the names of the `iris` data

```
The variable names of the iris data set are `r paste0(names(iris), collapse = ", ")`
```

should return

> The variable names of the iris data set are `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species`

However, if I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673252/how-to-apply-special-formatting-to-r-markdown-inline-code) approach and try to include backticks inside the inline code with e.g.

```
The variable names of the iris data set are `r paste0(paste0("`", names(iris), "`"), collapse = ", ")`
```

or any version of trying to escape the backtick character that I could come up with ended with an error message.

Comment: If backticks don’t work remember that you can always use inline HTML: `<code>` and `</code>` in place of backticks should work.

Comment: ah, nice. So this would also work with `\texttt{}`!

Comment: that even works inside the inline code using ``r paste0(paste0("\\texttt{", names(iris), "}"), collapse = ", ")``, which is even closer to what I was looking for. If you want to, you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... After experimenting a bit I came up with a pretty close solution to what I was looking for:

> backticks **around** the inline code

```
The variable names of the iris data set are ``r paste0(names(iris), collapse = ", ")``
```